# Fetch user roles from keycloak using django-allauth

Tags: django, keycloak, openid-connect, django-allauth

Using `django-allauth`, I've managed to get Django to login using Keycloak via openid-connect.  The problem I have now is that I can't figure out how to determine (in Django) which roles a user has (these are defined in Keycloak), in order to give the user appropriate permissions to do things.